# $k'(s_0)=0$ iff $k(s_0) = 1/r$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ or $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $\tau(s_0)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve parameterized by arc length (p.b.a.l.) with positive curvature and contained in a sphere of radius $r > 0$. If $s_0  \in  I$, show that the following
assertions are equivalent:

(i)$\hspace{0.1cm}$ $k'(s_0)=0$

(ii)$\hspace{0.1cm}$ $k(s_0) = 1/r$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$ or $\hspace{0.2cm}$ $\tau(s_0)=0$

**My attempt**

As usual, I want to prove that (i) implies (ii) and reciprocally that (ii) implies (1). But before this, I establish some general conditions:
If $ \alpha $ is contained in a sphere of radius $ r> 0 $ centered at the origin, then $ || \alpha || = r $, equivalently, $ || \alpha ||^2 = r ^ 2 $. Now, differentiating this expression three times, we have the following:

$$\frac{d}{ds}||\alpha||^2 = 2\alpha \cdot \alpha' = 0 \hspace{0.3cm}\text{so}\hspace{0.3cm} \alpha\cdot \alpha' = \alpha \cdot T = 0$$

$$\frac{d^2}{ds^2}||\alpha|^2 = \alpha \cdot T' + \alpha' \cdot T = \alpha \cdot T' + 1 = 0 \hspace{0.3cm} \text{(1)}$$

\begin{align*}
\frac{d^3}{ds^3}||\alpha||^2 &= k'(\alpha \cdot N) + k(\alpha \cdot N' + \alpha' \cdot N) \\
&= k'(\alpha \cdot N) + k(\alpha \cdot N')\\
&= k'(\alpha \cdot N) + k[\alpha \cdot(-kT - \tau B)]\\
&= k'(\alpha \cdot N) -k^2(\alpha \cdot T)-k\tau(\alpha \cdot B)\\
&= k'(\alpha \cdot N) - k\tau (\alpha \cdot B) = 0   \hspace{0.12cm} \text{(2)}
\end{align*}
Now if $k'(s_0)=0$, then the equation (2) implies that $\tau (s_0)(\alpha(s_0) \cdot B(s_0)) = 0$, but this does not give (ii).

Conversely, if $ k (s_0) = 1 / r $, clearly $ k '(s_0) = 0$. If $ \tau (s_0) = 0$ then equation (2) gives $ k '(s_0) (\alpha (s_0) \cdot N (s_0)) = 0 $, but I'm not sure if this implies that $ k' (s_0) = 0$.

I believe that at some point you must use equation (1). Where is my mistake in all this reasoning? I have not actually been able to conclude either of the two implications of the exercise.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, you're right, he edited that part. Thank you

Comment: You know that $T,N,B$ is an orthonormal basis and $\alpha\cdot T =0$. Can you finish?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm trying to prove your statement using the second Frenet equation $ N '= -kT - \tau B $. From this I have $ \alpha \cdot N '= -k \alpha \cdot T - \tau \alpha \cdot B $. So $ \alpha \cdot N '= 0 $. What else could I conclude from this. I'm right?

Comment: I think that your observation is very interesting and I want to know a formal proof

Comment: Just basic linear algebra, no Frenet. Write $\alpha$ as a linear combination of the orthonormal basis vectors, and think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use (1). You want to analyze (at $s_0$) the components $\alpha\cdot N$ and $\alpha\cdot B$. How can $\alpha\cdot B=0$? What does this say if you use (1)? (Also, how do you justify your "clearly"?)

**EDIT**: OK, note firstly that (1) says $k(\alpha\cdot N) = -1$, so $\alpha\cdot N\ne 0$ and $\alpha\cdot N = -1/k$ precisely when $\alpha = -rN$ and $k=1/r$. On the other hand, $\alpha$ and $N$ are parallel if and only if $\alpha\cdot B = 0$. You already observed that
$$k' = 0 \implies \tau = 0 \quad\text{or}\quad \alpha\cdot B = 0,$$
and the latter occurs if and only if $\alpha$ and $N$ are parallel and so $k = 1/r$. This establishes (1) $\implies$ (2).

Can you now finish (2) $\implies$ (1)?

Comment: Is it necessary to use cauchy schwarz inequality in (1) to prove (ii)?

Comment: Absolutely!!! And when does equality hold?

Comment: I know that the inequality holds when the vectors are parallel. So, thanks to your suggestion, I have from (1) that $ 1 = -k (\alpha \cdot N) \leq k || \alpha || = rk $. Now, I want to prove that (i) implies (ii). If I assume (i), then $ \tau (s_0) [\alpha (s_0) \cdot B (s_0)] =0 $, which means that $ \tau (s_0) = 0 $ or $ \alpha$ and $ B $ are perpendicular. The problem here is that I don't know how to combine these two results to obtain (ii).

Comment: This is precisely what I wrote in my answer. How can $\alpha\cdot B = 0$ occur?

Comment: I now have the above inequality, whose equality is maintained if the vectors $ \alpha $ and $ N $ are parallel. Regarding your question, $ \alpha \cdot B = 0 $ occurs when $ \alpha $ is orthogonal to $ B $. I have already scratched many pages and have not been able to use these conclusions. Could you give me a more detailed suggestion. There will probably be some implicit detail in all this that I have surely not discovered.

Comment: Thank you very much for directing me to the answer. The trick is when you say: "$  \alpha $ and $ N $ are parallel if and only if $ \alpha \cdot B = 0 $". Could you give me a suggestion to test this result?